# How do PHP array comparison functions work?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, comparison

I have the following function:

```
public static function CompareGroupReportEntries($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->visibility == $b->visibility) {
        return 0;
    } else{
        return $a->visibility < $b->visibility ? 1 : -1;        
    }
}
```

It works fine and I understand what it does. However I have difficulty in understanding it how it works. It is called on the following line;

```
usort($reports, "Utilities::CompareGroupReportEntries");
```

It is called outside of a loop, so how does it manage to sort all the objects in the array? What are the parameters $a and $b for?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: You should check the docs - http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php - the explanation is quite clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOur answer here: [PHP's USORT Callback Function Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091740/phps-usort-callback-function-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

it compares the elements of the array to determine their position.

so $a and $b are to elements of the list and from the result of the CompareGroupReportEntries-function it can say which value is bigger, so it can move it one up or down

Answer (score 0):

The function usort is a sorting function which takes an array and a callback function. here your function `CompareGroupReportEntries` is a callback function. PHP doesnt care whether your array elements are nubers or strings. it expects your callback function for the sorting criteria of the values of your array. iIf u are familiar with C then there is a `quicksort` function which also takes a callback function